AppCheck problems with flutter



I have added SHA-256 to AppCheck of the Google Play Console, and also when generating the .json of google service. In debug mode it works if I add the token it generates to the AppCheck token manager, but as soon as I generate the apk it no longer works.

Please edit your question to include code as text rather than images

Did you add the signing key or the upload key to the Firebase Console? For Play Integrity to work, it requires the signing key of the App from Google Play. Then the app must be downloaded from Google Play and ran on a real device.
